# Drawing many images inside UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

i'm looking for a way to draw multiple images (downloaded from a webservice) inside a single uiimageview. So it'd go like i downloaded image #1, and i'd like to draw it inside rect (0,0,100,100) then #2 at (0,100,100,100) etc.
I'd like to then be able to take the entire composition and save it as an image in camera roll.
thanks in advance for help
greetings
peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a UIView, then add multiple UIImageViews as subviews.

You may use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to extract an image from the UIView.

Comment: Fantastic, i wasn't aware of that CGImage functionality. Thanks!